# What should I do stay a little bit more or going abroad after my internship?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, one-way, working-visas

I just finished my university. I am doing an internship, I am also the possibility to find an entry level position in IT in 'great country'  but I have 1 year of experience in computer security / offensive security. I have not worked in the area but I have had many practical exercises in virtualized environments.

Should  I go to great countries such as France, Canada, USA , Germany, UK? I will soon be an engineer in computer science with specialization in computer security / cyber security. I have nothing, not even a passport, but even if I had a visa it does not help me if I go to work. I speak English and others.

Comment: Are you talking about a gap year? Or do you want to find an entry level position in IT in 'great county'? Where are you studying now?  China? Brazil? Unclear. Close voting.

Comment: It's not clear that this is a travel question.

Comment: I meant the way to find an entry level position in IT in ''great county'', should I stay a little bit more or should I go abroad to the adventure?

Comment: @AronImperial, if you are young and you can afford it, taking a gap year is a good idea. See the world, see different societies, travel. If you are looking at your professional development, finding a job might be better. But you shouldn't see an entry level job as adventure, that's the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Would the close voters care to explain how this is a question about being an expatriate? It's a purely opinion-based "Where should I go on holiday?" question.

Answer (score 1):

A number of Western nations have programs for highly skilled graduates, including the [EU Blue Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Card_(European_Union)).

- If a company is willing to hire you for 1.5 times the average annual salary, you get a work visa. For details, please ask at [Expatriates StackExchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).
- You might be able to get a visa as a [jobseeker](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324661/en/), which might be on topic here. That requires a degree from a reputable university. It might be on topic here, because it isn't about permanent migration, but I guess expats can help you better.

You will need a passport to apply to a visa, so getting started with that now is a good idea.